# openDDS on raspberry pi with raspbian

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, ace, data-distribution-service

Is it possible to build openDDS and the required ACE+TAO on an raspberry pi with raspbian?

I want to build it for java, so I tried the way described in $DDS_ROOT/java/INSTALL inlcuding the tips from [here](http://ms-cheminfo.com/?q=node/56)

but if I make

```
cd $ACE_ROOT/ace
make ACE
```

it ends with this error

```
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/MEM_SAP.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/MEM_Stream.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo name for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/MEM_Stream.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/MMAP_Memory_Pool.o:(.rodata+0x34): multiple definition of `typeinfo name for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/MMAP_Memory_Pool.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x18): multiple definition of `typeinfo for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/Pagefile_Memory_Pool.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo name for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/Pagefile_Memory_Pool.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/PI_Malloc.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo name for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
.shobj/PI_Malloc.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for ACE_Singleton<ACE_Based_Pointer_Repository, ACE_RW_Thread_Mutex>'
.shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libACE.so.6.3.1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bf/openDDS/ACE_wrappers/ace'
make: *** [ACE] Error 2
```

any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with visibility and gcc 4.x. Try to add

```
#define ACE_GCC_HAS_TEMPLATE_INSTANTIATION_VISIBILITY_ATTRS 1
```

to your ace/config.h file or

```
no_hidden_visibility=1
```

to your include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU